# Sufficient Statistic for non-exponential family distribution

Tags: probability, inference, exponential-family, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

**Question:** Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be an iid sample from $N(\theta , 4 \theta^2 )$. I want to show that this model is not a member of the exponential family and to find a sufficient statistic for $\theta$

**Attempt**: 
\begin{align*}
f(~\underline{x}~;\theta) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{8 \pi \theta^2}} \exp\left(\frac{-1}{8 \theta^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \theta)^2\right)\\
&=\exp \left(\ln(8\pi \theta^2)^{-n/2}- \frac{1}{8 \theta^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \frac{1}{4 \theta} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \frac{n}{8}\right)
\end{align*}

So clearly this is not a member of the exponential family as it is the representation of a two dimensional exponential family, but we only have one parameter.

I am struggling to find a sufficient statistic however, can I have a two dimensional statistic if I am estimating one parameter?

**Update**

So after doing a similar question I am fairly certain that a sufficient statistic is given by: $S=(S_1,S_2) =(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i) $. So i guess my question just boils down to how can we have a two dimensional statistic to estimate one parameter, seems counter intuitive?

Also, I've learned that this is a member of the curved exponential family, a further generalization of the exponential family.

Comment: You will find that this sufficient statistic is not complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

First ***this is an exponential family*** [(as shown by the above excerpt from Brown, 1986)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215466757) since the density writes down as
$$\exp\{\Phi_1(\theta) S_1({\mathbf x})+\Phi_2(\theta) S_2({\mathbf x})-\Psi(\theta)\}$$against a particular dominating measure.
That the two coefficients $\Phi_1(\theta)$ and $\Phi_2(\theta)$ are connected with a functional relation is not an issue: they also both depend deterministically on $\theta$. The fact that $\theta$ is one-dimensional and the family is two-dimensional is a case of *curved exponential families*  (see excerpt below from [Brown, 1986](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215466757)). This family can be extended to a (full) truly two-dimensional parameter space, of which the ${\cal N}(\theta, 4\theta²)$ is a special case. Or a *curve* like $\Psi_1=\Psi_2^2/2$ in the extended (full) parameter space. But ***curved exponential families are special cases of exponential families, not generalisations.***

[image]

Another reason for this distribution to be from an exponential family is that there exists a sufficient statistic of dimension two, whatever the sample size $n$ is. By the Darmois-Pitman-Koopman lemma this can only occur in an exponential family.

For the same reason as before, there can be a sufficient statistic of dimension two and a parameter of dimension one and this is not a contradiction, as the same sufficient statistic of dimension two serves for the extended (full) exponential family with two parameters. Examples (or paradoxes) where this happens abound in the literature. See for instance [Romano and Siegel (1987)](https://amzn.to/2EWvpvI). As pointed out by Kjetil B Halvorsen, these "paradoxes" are generally connected with a lack of completeness.

Comment: How does "there exists a sufficient statistic of dimension two" work with a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$ with sufficient statistic $\left(X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\right)$?

Comment: @Henry: Some distributions with varying support, while outside the exponential family framework, do allow for sufficient statistics.

Answer (score 0):

There are different definitions of "sufficient statistic(s)" and "exponential family" by different authors.  I wish the theoretical statisticians can agree on a single set of definitions to avoid confusing the world.

Most of authors do not require the dimensionality of sufficient statistics to match that of parameters.
Examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic and "The Theory of Point Estimation" by Lehmann and Casella.

A few authors do. Examples: The great Mr. Fisher himself, and "Econometrics: Statistical Foundations and Applications" by Dhrymes.

Under the "more common" definition of exponential family, OP's example is a curved exponential, where the number of "natural" parameters $s$, exceeds the number of "original" parameters $k$. When $s = k$, it is called full-rank. It should be noted that $s < k$ can never happen, if the original parameters are identified in any open $k$ dimensional rectangle in $R^k$,