# Minimum dimension of sufficient statistics

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, sufficient-statistics, fisher-information

Suppose that we have a parameter of $k$-dimensions. Say, for example, for $N(u,\theta)$ both unknown then the parameter is of two dimensions, and $n$ i.i.d. observations.

Is it possible to find a sufficient statistic that has dimension less than $k$? For example, for normal distribution the minimal sufficient statistics is proven to be (sample mean, sample variance) so it is not possible for normal distribution, but I am wondering if this holds in general.

Answer (score 4):

Since sufficiency of fixed dimension only occurs in exponential families ([Darmois-Pitman-Koopman lemma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/277434/7224)), apart from distributions with varying support like the Uniform, let us consider an exponential family with parameter $\theta$ and density [against a fixed dominating measure]
$$f_\theta(x)=\exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i(\theta) T_i(x) -\psi(\theta)\right\}$$ 
Assuming the functions $a_i$ are linearly independent on the maximal support of $\theta$ (namely, the range of $\theta$'s for which the density is integrable), the model associated with this density can be reparameterised in $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)$ which varies in (at least) the parameter space
$$A=\left\{\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k);\,\exists\theta\in\Theta, \alpha_i=a_i(\theta) \right\}$$*at least*, since the parameter space can be naturally expanded to its natural limit
$$A=\left\{\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k);\,\displaystyle{\int \exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i T_i(x)\right\}\text{d}\lambda(x)}<\infty \right\}\,,$$and that the functions $T_i$ are also linearly independent over the support $\cal X$ of $X$, the statistic
$$T=(T_1(X),\ldots,T_k(X)$$is sufficient and with density
$$g_\alpha(t)=\exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i t_i-\mu(\alpha)\right\}$$
against the appropriate dominating measure. Therefore on the natural space of the exponential family (which may be [larger](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/341246/7224) than the original parameter space), the sufficient statistic is of the same dimension as the parameter. Even though the domain of variation of $T(x)$ can be constrained by non-linear relations, there is a sample size after which the dimensional constraint vanishes.

A completely different approach, avoiding exponential families, is provided by

> Edward W. Barankin and Melvin Katz, Jr.
>   [Sufficient Statistics of Minimal Dimension](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25048419?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
>   Sankhyā: The Indian Journal of Statistics 
>   Vol. 21, No. 3/4 (Aug., 1959), pp. 217-246

and they show the following result

[image]

where $r$ is the dimension of the sufficient statistic $T$ and $\rho(x^0)$ is the (local) rank of the second derivative of the log-likelihood in $\theta$ and $x$ [the definition is a bit too intricate to be reproduced here].