# Proof of Pitman–Koopman–Darmois theorem

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, inference, sufficient-statistics

Where can I find a proof of Pitman–Koopman–Darmois theorem? I have googled for quite some time. Strangely, many notes mention this theorem yet none of them present the proof.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/309089/119261

Answer (score 6):

The proof is somewhat technical and can be found in its original form here:

On Distributions Admitting a Sufficient Statistic --
 Koopman: 
http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/koopman-on.pdf

Comment: Folks may be interested in [this discussion about a possible problem with Koopman's proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309089/undergraduate-level-proofs-of-the-pitman-koopman-darmois-theorem#comment740432_309156) (in the context of a question about whether there is a more elementary derivation).