# Minimal Sufficient Statistic for Gaussians with different means

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, sufficient-statistics, factorisation-theorem

I have the following problems on my Statistics course (using Casella and Berger's book) problem set:

> 1) Let $Y_{i} = X_{i}'\theta + U_{i}$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^k$
>   and $U_{i}$ are iid $N(0, \sigma^2)$ random variables and $X_{i}$ is a
>   fixed vector for each $i$. Find the minimal sufficient statistic when
>   $\sigma^2$ is known.
>
> 2) Find the minimal sufficient statistic when $\sigma^2$ is unknown.

I was able to represent this model in a vectorial way, write down the vectorial joint density for $Y$ and show that the OLS regressor of $Y$ on $X$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$. However, I'm having trouble with showing that it's the minimal one and also with the case when $\sigma^2$ is unknown. Any ideas how to procede?

Comment: One thing that might help is that the minimum dimension of a sufficient statistic is the dimension of the parameter vector, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159101/minimum-dimension-of-sufficient-statistics.  So if you can show that the dimension of the OLS regressor equals the dimension of $\theta$, and that the OLS regressor is a sufficient statistic (which you have done), then you can conclude that the OLS regressor is minimal sufficient.

Comment: You should add the [self-study] tag, please!

Comment: @jbowman I wasn't aware of this result. This helps a lot.